# Use of the 'bird' when referring to a young maiden

Tags: reason-why

In the Gilbert and Sullivan Opera 'The Mikado'  (mid-late nineteenth Century) - the words 'Yes, I knew the bird intimately' appear the circumstances which point to a pun meaning a young lady,  this predates the 1915 supposed 'new' use of the word in this context by 50 years  is it not fair then to assume this can be said to be a possible contender for the first use in modern times?

Comment: I've voted your question up, since it is a reasonable and well-worded one. I've also voted as a duplicate. If that question is different, please edit to explain how!

Comment: I too have voted it up for the same reason and because it probably invalidates the duplicate's answer.

Comment: I don’t think that “bird” is used as a punning reference to a  young woman in _The Mikado”. The speaker (Koko) is referring to an actual bird (a titwillow) who died of a

Comment: @marcellothearcane Is it well-worded?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I think so. There's potential. They are a new user, and this is a lot better than most new user's first questions! I hope you stick around, Cassion53.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm sure you are correct. Koko has just been singing about a little bird (male) which supposedly died for love, and Katisha expresses sympathy (as he had intended).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of the original text.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes - perhaps you're right.